# Query regarding the functionality of repeat().until()

Tags: gremlin

Data: [Tinkerpop Modern sample graph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/images/tinkerpop-modern.png)

Query:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).repeat(both()).until(hasLabel("person")).path().by("name")
==>[marko,vadas]
==>[marko,josh]
==>[marko,lop,marko]
==>[marko,lop,josh]
==>[marko,lop,peter]
```

What [doc](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#repeat-step) says:

> ...If until() comes after repeat() it is do/while looping. If until()
>   comes before repeat() it is while/do looping...

**Doubt**:

Shouldn't `until` terminate the query after first match `marko-vadas`? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It terminates the traverser on this path, otherwise you would get `[marko,vadas,marko]` next. The other paths were found by other traversers. If you only care about the first path, add a `.limit(1)`.

```
gremlin> g.V(1).repeat(both()).until(hasLabel("person")).limit(1).path().by("name")
==>[marko,vadas]
```